# Parse Specific Elements DOM - Java

Tags: java, dom, element

I believe this is a simple question but I am having trouble to find out how it works.

That's the XML file (from www.w3schools.com):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

As you can see the book XQuery Kick Start has more than one author.
But I cant find a way to get the right number of authors.
Thats my code:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    File fXmlFile = new File("\books.xml");        
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Category : " + eElement.getAttribute("category"));
            System.out.println("Title : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Author : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Year : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("year").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent()); 
        }
    }
```

But as Result I'll be getting only one author:

```
Root element :bookstore
----------------------------

Current Element :book
Categoria do Livro : cooking
Titulo : Everyday Italian
Autor : Giada De Laurentiis
Ano : 2005
Price : 30.00

Current Element :book
Categoria do Livro : children
Titulo : Harry Potter
Autor : J K. Rowling
Ano : 2005
Price : 29.99

Current Element :book
Categoria do Livro : web
Titulo : XQuery Kick Start
Autor : James McGovern
Ano : 2003
Price : 49.99

Current Element :book
Categoria do Livro : web
Titulo : Learning XML
Autor : Erik T. Ray
Ano : 2003
Price : 39.95
```

Does anyone knows a good method to get the right number of elements?
*sorry about the long question, I didnt know how to express myself so I had to paste here*
*I'm new to DOM*

Comment: You would need to iterate over the `NodeList` returned  by `getElementsByTagName("author")` instead of getting `.item(0)`.

Comment: Take out .item(0) as it's restricting you to only the first in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are getting the first author always, as you're retrieving the first item of the nodelist

```
getElementsByTagName("author").item(0)
```

Try iterating them, as there could be more than one

```
for (int i = 0; i < eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").getLength(); i++)
     System.out.println("Author : " + 
           eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(i).getTextContent());
```