# DOM Java - Parse right number of attributes from empty nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom

A few weeks ago I made a question about counting node elements and got a nice answer that helped me to understand many things. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646495/parse-specific-elements-dom-java).

But it turns out that now I have a different situation and I can't find a good solution for that.

That's the code I need to work with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
    <books>
        <book id="1">
            <title="Everyday Italian" category="cooking" year="2005" price="30.00"/>
            <author name ="Giada De Laurentiis"/>
        </book>
        <book id="2">
            <title="XQuery Kick Start" category="web" year="2003" price="49.99"/>
            <author name ="James McGovern"/>
            <author name ="Per Bothner"/>
            <author name ="Kurt Cagle"/>
            <author name ="James Linn"/>
        </book>
    <books>
</bookstore>
```

Using this to get the number of authors (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646495/parse-specific-elements-dom-java) the previous question to understand):

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").getLength()
```

returns me NULL since there is no element inside , just parameters.

That's kinda obvious but when I create a NodeList to parse the authors

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("author");
```

I get all the 5 authors
So If I only need the authors of the second book I will be getting wrong information.

I would like to know a good method to parse the right number of authors from each book.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is invalid...

Comment: 1- <title=... 2- <books>...<books>, these make the XML invalid...

Answer (score 0):

While a little more work to get it started, I prefer to use XPath, it's a lot more robust way to query XML...

After updating the XML example so it could be read...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
    <books>
        <book id="1">
            <title name="Everyday Italian" category="cooking" year="2005" price="30.00"/>
            <author name ="Giada De Laurentiis"/>
        </book>
        <book id="2">
            <title name="XQuery Kick Start" category="web" year="2003" price="49.99"/>
            <author name ="James McGovern"/>
            <author name ="Per Bothner"/>
            <author name ="Kurt Cagle"/>
            <author name ="James Linn"/>
        </book>
    </books>
</bookstore>
```

I used this...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TestXPath100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("Test.xml"));
            XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("//author");
            NodeList nl = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println(nl.getLength());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which outputs `5`.

Basically, the xPath query looks for all nodes, anywhere in the document that are named `author`

Take a look at [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for more details

**Updated with additional example**

If you have taken the time to read the [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/), you would know that XPath is a query language for XML (a bit like SQL is a query language for database)...

So I changed the code to dump the `name` attribute of all the matched elements and used the query `//book[title[@name='Everyday Italian']]/author`

```
XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("//book[title[@name='Everyday Italian']]/author");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nl.item(index);
    System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name"));
}
```

And it outputted...

```
name="Giada De Laurentiis"
```

I changed the query to `//book[title[@name='XQuery Kick Start']]/author` and it outputted...

```
name="James McGovern"
name="Per Bothner"
name="Kurt Cagle"
name="James Linn"
```

Comment: Yea, that's the main problem :( I need a method that could parse only the authors from the book I need, not all the authors that exist in my bookstore.

Comment: XPath can do that. Which book do you want?

Comment: XPath is a query language for XML, a lot like SQL is a query language for databases.  Take a look at the update...

Answer (score 0):

Use eElement.getElementsByTagName("book") to find the books, then for each book element from the list you can use bElement.getElementsByTagName("author") to find the authors.